# PreferenceKey issue - SwiftUI sometimes seems to generate additional views that show up as default values in reduce of a PreferenceKey?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following function that moves a view so it fits into a certain rectangle using PreferenceKeys.

The function looks like that:

```
struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize,
                       nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        let otherSize = nextValue()
        print("reduce.value is: \(value)")
        print("reduce.nextValue is: \(otherSize)")
        // 
        // the asignment blow (although in many examples) is a problem - but no clue where 
        // the second key is coming from?
        // the value of otherSize is the default Size.zero, coming from a secondary view
        value = otherSize
        // should be: value = otherSize != defaultValue ? otherSize : value
    }
}

extension View {
    func moveIfFrame(withOrigin point:Binding<CGPoint>, outside screen: CGRect) -> some View {
        background(GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            // Color is the only child of background - or not?
            Color.clear.preference(
                key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
                value: size
            )
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { size in
            var offset = CGPoint.zero
            offset.x = screen.maxX - (point.x.wrappedValue + size.width)
            offset.y = screen.maxY - (point.y.wrappedValue + size.height)
            point.wrappedValue = CGPoint(x: point.x.wrappedValue + ( offset.x < 0 ? offset.x : 0) , y: point.y.wrappedValue + (offset.y < 0 ? offset.y : 0 ))
        }
    }
}


// Usage
//
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var point = CGPoint(x:2000,y:2000)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack(alignment:.topLeading) {
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(.green)
                Text("Foo")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(Color.red)
    
                    // Operator used here
                    .moveIfFrame(withOrigin: $point, outside: proxy.frame(in: .local))
 
                    .offset(x: point.x, y:point.y)
            }
            .background(Color.green)
            
        }
    }
}
```

It works in most cases, where reduce of the SizePreferenceKey never gets called - which is kind of logical as background only has one Child: Color and the PreferenceKey is clear, so no reduce necessary.
But in my production code, in some cases all of the sudden reduce is being called and a second (newValue) with default Rect.zero shows up. The problem can easily be fixed, but for the sake of my mental state I want to know what is going on. Since the structure under background in moveIfFrame is build in my function, I would expect that there is always going to be just one view, hence one PreferenceKey value coming up the hirarchy and no call to reduce - ever.

Does SwiftUI sometimes insert Views? Or where is that second PreferenceKey value coming from sometimes? Many examples circulating in the web use a similar implementation I have in my reduce function (with an asignment of value=newValue) - which seems to be not correct.

So my question is: Where could that second view possibly come from? In what situations? Or how can I figure out what's going on (the debugger crashes when I try to get to the view hierarchy)?

In any case for a function like mine above, reduce needs to ignore defaultValues (or be just empty - I guess) - despite most examples having an asignment in reduce...

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: *Color is the only child of background - or not?* - in your case it is GeometryReader, it is also a View.

Comment: *Does SwiftUI sometimes insert Views? Or where is that second PreferenceKey value coming from sometimes?* - in might depend on your production code, so set breakpoint into reduce and you'll see where it is called from.

Comment: Good point with GeometryReader - the GeometryReader and not Color should be the only child of background then - still only one - and debugging into reduce does not help, because the call stack does not reveal the object that is providing the second value.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue as well, don't suppose you had any luck with this?

Comment: I solved it with "value = otherSize != defaultValue ? otherSize : value" in reduce.